# PDE for a damped oscillator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I'm studying a PDE that describes a damped oscillator, given by:

$$u_t + uu_x = -\gamma u $$

with initial conditions $u(x,0)=f(x)$. I derived the characteristics as:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = u$$ and $$\frac{du}{dt} = -\gamma u$$

so that $x = ut+c_1$ and $u = c_2\exp(-\gamma t)$.

I'm nut sure how to proceed since the textbook only quotes the solution as

$$ u = f(\zeta)\exp(-\gamma t)$$

and

$$x = \frac{f(\zeta)}{\gamma}( 1- \exp(-\gamma t))+\zeta$$

Comment: Your expression $x=ut+c_1$ isn't correct; since $u$ depends on $t$, you can't treat it as a constant when you integrate the equation for $x$.

Comment: How do I correct this? I'm not sure how to get the desired solution

Comment: You've already determined $u(t) = c_2 e^{-\gamma t}$. So next you have to integrate $x'(t)=c_2 e^{-\gamma t}$ in order to find $x(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$u_t + uu_x = -\gamma u $$
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{du}{-\gamma u}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{du}{-\gamma u}$ :
$$u+\gamma x=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dx}{c_1-\gamma x}$ :
$$\gamma x+e^{-\gamma t}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE on implicit form $c_1=F(c_2)$ is :
$$\boxed{u=\gamma x+F(\gamma x+e^{-\gamma t})}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to the initial condition).

Condition :

$$u(x,0)=f(x)=\gamma x+F(\gamma x+1)$$
$$F(\gamma x+1)=f(x)-\gamma x$$
Let $\gamma x+1=X\quad\implies\quad x=\frac{X-1}{\gamma}$
$$F(X)=f\left(\frac{X-1}{\gamma}\right)-X+1$$
Now the function $F(X)$ is known. We put it into the above general solution where $X=\gamma x+e^{-\gamma t}$
$$u=\gamma x+f\left(\frac{(\gamma x+e^{-\gamma t})-1}{\gamma}\right)-(\gamma x+e^{-\gamma t})+1$$

$$\boxed{u(x,t)=f\left(x+\frac{e^{-\gamma t}-1}{\gamma}\right)+1-e^{-\gamma t}}$$

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you. Do you know how to calculate wave breaking?